# Odds of an event happening over a long period of time

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

If there is a fluctuating chance of rain throughout the day how do you calculate the chance that it will rain at some point throughout the day? For example, tomorrow there is a six hour period with the chance of rain varying from 40-60% by the hour. Would there be a 60% that it would rain at all or is there a calculation that would result an a higher chance of rain occurring at some point throughout the day? Thank you.

Comment: Is your question specifically about interpreting weather forecasts' 'probability of precipitation'? If so, you also need to take into account that the weather forecast refers to an area over which the rain might fall, as well as the probability/'confidence' that any rain (over a minimum threshold) will fall in that hour. Wikipedia have a page explaining this, as one example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_of_precipitation

Comment: For a particular region: if there in a six-hour period during which the probability of rain is .55 in each hour (independently) then the probability of **_no_** rain during the six-hour period is $(.45)^6$ and the probability of some rain in the period is $1 - (.45)^6 \approx 0.99.$ But after reading what these forecasts mean (in @lzy's link), I'm not sure conditions are met for that computation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a marcov chain. Here is a link. http://setosa.io/ev/markov-chains/

Comment: True, but how do you determine the values of the conditional probabilities needed to make a Markov model?

Comment: It depends how accurate you want to be. You could break your matrix down into three categories sunny, cloudy, and raining and then calculate the probabilies of going to from one condition to another over a six hour period. That's a pretty elementary way to look at it but might give you a start.

Comment: Could you show us how Markov chains are applicable?  As far as I can tell, the question posits an inhomogeneous Poisson process and asks for a property of it (namely, the chance of zero events during a specified period).  No Markov chains appear to be involved or needed to address this.